# Следующее занятие в среду 5 февраля

Tags: пунктуация

"Следующее занятие в среду 5 февраля". Нужна ли запятая перед числом?

Answer (score 2):

*Следующее занятие в среду, **5 февраля**.*

Такой вариант более предпочтителен, дата идет как **уточнение**.

Без запятой отношения между обстоятельствами неоднородные: формально можно подумать, что мы будем ждать, когда среда совпадет с этой датой.